# Nativescript: mimic material design effect with floating action button

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm using Nativescript 1.6 and this component https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-floatingactionbutton

I would like to have some nice "material design effect" when you click on this button and then navigate to another page. It's a bit hacky but it does the job and looks quite nice (i probably should use fragment transitions with shared elements when i was in native Android world, but im not)

My current attempt:

XML:

```
<FAB:fab tap="tap"
  loaded="buttonLoaded"
  row="1"
  icon="res://ic_add_white_24dp"
  rippleColor="#f1f1f1"
  class="fab-button" />
```

JS:

```
fabButton.icon = ""; // Error! ResourceNotFoundException
fabButton.animate({
  scale: { x: 20, y: 20 },
  translate: { x: -200, y: -200 },
  duration: 300
}).then(function(){
  navigation.goToDetailPage();

  fabButton.animate({ // reset button to original state
    scale: { x: 1, y: 1 },
    translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    delay: 100,
    duration: 0
  });
});
```

2 questions:

- How can i remove the icon, just for a nicer effect? "", {}, null are not allowed, should i really create a transparent png for this?
- Is there a better way to restore/reset element after an animation?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the exception is `ResourceNotFoundException` that looks like a native exception thrown so it doesn't look like you'll be able to set a null value. Your best option is probably an empty .png. I suppose the plugin could check for a null value and bypass the native exception but for now that's not the case. You could make a PR with this feature if you wanted.
2. As for resetting an element to its original state, what you are doing is what I would do. I don't think there would be a "better" way because once you've changed the state with the initial animation, the native `setTranslateX/Y` and other methods to run the animation have changed the items location/position/color, etc. So what you are doing is probably the best approach.

I'd like to see this animation if you don't mind, looks like something other devs might want :)  Maybe record a .gif and attach here for others to see as a reference. If you don't have a tool to record a .gif here is what I use: http://www.cockos.com/licecap/ when I record from the emulators.

Hope this helps some.